# Connection error SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server but I always get the following error code:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Accesso non riuscito per l'utente 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Accesso non riuscito per l'utente 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Impossibile aprire il database "CMR" richiesto dall'account di accesso. Accesso non riuscito. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Impossibile aprire il database "CMR" richiesto dall'account di accesso. Accesso non riuscito. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Accesso non riuscito per l'utente 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Accesso non riuscito per l'utente 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Impossibile aprire il database "CMR" richiesto dall'account di accesso. Accesso non riuscito. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Impossibile aprire il database "CMR" richiesto dall'account di accesso. Accesso non riuscito. ) )

My PHP code:

```
$serverName = "UTENTE-PC\SQLEXPRESS";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CMR");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I don't understand what do I have to do!?

P.S. I'm using WAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `Accesso non riuscito per l'utente 'NT'` into Google Translator produces `Login failed for user 'NT'`. So it looks like you're using the wrong database credentials.

Comment: In PHP I didn't specify the UID and the PWD so it is using the windows authentication mode

Comment: Is your SQL Server configured to allow windows authentication? http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLMixedMode.aspx

Comment: Yes,because when I open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I use windows authentication

Comment: Is your webserver running as the same Windows user?

Comment: I could tell you if it was IIS, but not sure about Apache. One sec, let me Google it ... ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56039/discussion-between-antox-and-dan).